# E: Malfored entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list (Suite) E: The list of sources could not be read

Tags: virtualbox, sudo

I was installing virtualbox and when i enter this:

```
$ echo "deb {arch=amd64} http://virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian
> (lsb_release -cs)contrib
> (lsb_release -cs) contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

This showed:

```
[sudo] password for marie: 
deb {arch=amd64} http://virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian
(lsb_release -cs)contrib
(lsb_release -cs) contrib
```

I then try to do:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you certain that you want the upstream virtualbox? The version in the Ubuntu repositories works very well and is much simpler to install.

Comment: The command should have been `echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -cs) contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` all in one line.

Comment: I disagree that this question is a duplicate. The problem isn't that there's a malformed line that needs to be removed, the problem is that the user typed something incorrect and it caused a malformed line. The answer (which @muru thankfully gave in the comments) is to overwrite the incorrectly created file with a new one created using the right command.